# How can I force Grails to use only one language?

Tags: grails, internationalization

I want to make my Grails application support only one language, that I can define somewhere, completely ignoring the client's headers or the "lang" parameter. Is there any way I can do so? Thanks.

Answer (score 19):

Define a `LocaleResolver` bean in your `config/spring/resources.groovy` to set the default locale.

```
beans = {
   localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver) {
      defaultLocale = new Locale("de","DE")
      java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale)
   }
}
```

This is useful if you don't have to deal with the `lang` parameter - otherwise it would get overridden. To even ignore the `lang` parameter value you can set the locale in a `Filter` upon each request:

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils as RCU
...
def filters = {
    all(controller:'*', action:'*') {

        before = {
            def locale = new Locale("sv","SV")
            RCU.getLocaleResolver(request).setLocale(request, response, locale)                  
        }

    }
}
```

This approach seems a bit repetitive as Locale is re-set on every request. It would be more elegant to disable the browsers locale detection via an config option.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question above. ArmlessJohn specifically requests the ability to *override* the language setting from the user.  This just sets the default.  Please read the answer you linked to again.

Comment: CAREFUL! java.util.Locale.setDefault(defaultLocale) will change the default locale for the entire JVM, which may be very bad, since a lot of code thinks that "i".toUpperCase().equals("I") in all locales. It doesn't...
A lot of clever utilities make assumptions like that.

Answer (score 6):

The default `LocaleResolver` of Grails is `SessionLocaleResolver`. If you want to always use de_DE you can change this to `FixedLocaleResolver`.

```
beans {
  localeResolver(FixedLocaleResolver) {
      locale = new Locale("de", "DE")
  }
}
```

If you want to restrict to a set of locales, then you will need a filter, and use the `SessionLocaleResolver#setLocale(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Locale locale)` method.

Comment: I have problems with your solution "Bean property 'locale' is not writable or has an invalid setter method." ... "Invalid property 'locale' of bean class [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver]"

Comment: This seems to work -> localResolver(FixedLocaleResolver, Locale.US)

Answer (score 5):

remove all `messages_xx.properties` files and keep only the `messages.properties` files. 
This is the default message bundle to which the system will always fall back if it can't find the right message bundle.

This way you can still use messages (and thus keep the option to nationalize your app) but users will get always the same language.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in order to override the default localResolver bean

```
beans = {
    localeResolver(org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.FixedLocaleResolver) {
        setLocale(Locale.US)
    }
}
```