# Force i18n locale to be da_DK in grails 2.x

Tags: grails, localization, internationalization, grails-2.0

I'm new to grails and I'm trying to achieve the following:

I would like to force programmatically a specific locale for my app to use.

I found a few answers but none of them seems to work. What I found:

[Grails Locale not set for Spock unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30284984/grails-locale-not-set-for-spock-unit-tests)

I tried exactly what's written there (To change the locale to 'da_DK') but I get the following:

```
LocaleContextHolder.locale:              'iw_IL'
java.util.Locale.getDefault():           'da_DK'
RequestContextUtils.getLocale(request):  'iw_IL'
session['SessionLocaleResolver.LOCALE']: ''
```

Why won't all of the variables change? Is there another way to make it work?

Comment: Would you like to set the locale while unit/integration testing or when its deployed as war`

Comment: In the end I would like to achieve both

Comment: Can you explain why you want to change the locale? What would you like to achieve? Why don't you just extend your resource bundle in `messages.properties`. Are you aware of changing the locale by the query string parameter `?lang=de`?

Comment: Yes i know about the lang param. I'm trying to use the i18n engine to provide different strings for different clients that use the same program.

Comment: and why don't you simply use `message_da.properties` for danish and `message_en.properties` for english? Why do you want to programmatically change the locale?

Comment: I don't want the application to detect the locale automatic because i will use each locale file as a different set of strings and not as simple translations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well.. i found out what the problem was. after changing the code in the file resources.groovy the server must be restarted so the changes will take place.